# ContentLoadingProgressBar downloaded value keep same when activity change

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I have three activities and one activity display the  `ContentLoadingProgressBar`
in `onProgressUpdate`.

```
Like This-mPogressBar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0].toString()));
```

My question-when I change the activity `progressbar` again start from (0).
how to keep display downloaded value from there when I came from any activity?

Comment: you can't move between activities during the download and display the progress as you wish because the task connected to the activity to display progress and once you leave this activity the activity is dead , when you come back to that activity you will open a new activity not goes back to the old dead one

Comment: but i need to display same progress from there  where i leave.

Comment: So do it in a fragment as well , you can't distroy the activity and still display progress